# Pasting Excel Table in an Outlook email: it looks back

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I have been able to run the following code for copying an Excel range into an Outlook email (using the code provided by Ron de Bruin:

```
    Sub SendEMail(SheetName As String, EmailBody As String, EmailSubject As String, MyAttachment As String)
    ' You need to use this module with the RangetoHTML subroutine.
    ' Works in Excel 2000, Excel 2002, Excel 2003, Excel 2007, Excel 2010, Outlook 2000, Outlook 2002, Outlook 2003, Outlook 2007, and Outlook 2010.
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Only send the visible cells in the selection.
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range(EmailBody).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    ' You can also use a range with the following statement.
    ' Set rng = Sheets("YourSheet").Range("D4:D12").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected. " & _
               vbNewLine & "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        '.To = "ron@debruin.nl"
        '.CC = ""
        '.BCC = ""
        .subject = "Resumen de " & EmailSubject
        .htmlbody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
        ' display the e-mail message.
        .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    ActiveSheet.Protect
End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
    ' By Ron de Bruin.
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        '.Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        '.Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        '.Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close SaveChanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

It works fine for sending, but problem is when opening. The table appears too wide for the reader

Is there anything that can be done to correct this and have the columns with the same width than in Excel?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the code are a little complicated, and with this code you can only insert in the mail the values of the range selected...
If you want add the width of the columns, you can add the code:

```
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
        ' Code ADDED
        i = 1
        For Each xx In rng.Columns
            TempWB.Sheets(1).Columns(i).ColumnWidth = xx.ColumnWidth
            i = i + 1
        Next
        ' Code ADDED
'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With
```

the only 5 lines between the two **With** block. The code set the original width in the new sheet (temp sheet).
For me it's most simple to copy and paste the Range directly in the HTMLBody of the mail. In that case you have ALL the format of the table (example: color, height, font ...). To do that a portion of code can be:

```
    Set mailApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set mail = mailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    mail.Display
    mail.To = "A@a.com"
    mail.Subject = "subject" & Now

    Dim Clip As MSForms.DataObject
    Set Clip = New MSForms.DataObject
    Clip.SetText ("test ... body" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
                & "this is another line " & vbCrLf _
                & "this is another line again " & vbNewLine & " ")
    Clip.PutInClipboard

    Set wEditor = mailApp.ActiveInspector.wordEditor
    wEditor.Application.Selection.Paste

    Selection.Copy
    wEditor.Application.Selection.Paste
    ' mail.send
```